# Joining tables with one to many relationship into in data stage

Tags: etl, datastage

I have two tables.  One is the parent the other the child.  Example below:

```
Table 1
ALERT_ID |DATE      | PLACE
123      |2016-07-23| cALI

TABLE 2
UNIQUE KEY|ALERT_ID |TYPE  |NUMBER
1         |123      |1     |45678
2         |123      |5     |96321
```

For context:

Let's say `type=1` then `number` is `building number` and `type 5` is `room number`. An alert can occur in a building but not in a room.

```
BUT HERE'S THE RESULT I'M LOOKING FOR 
ALERT_ID |DATE      | PLACE | BUILDING NR |  ROOM_NR
123      |2016-07-23| cALI  | 45678       |  96321
```

What would be the best stage to accomplish this? any help would be appreciated especially with screenshots if able.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a database stage with Table1 - select all alerts.
Use a sort stages to sort by alert_id and join (inner join) by alert_id

```
                              DB             DB
                            (table2)       (table2)
                          where type=1    where type=5
                               |              |
                             Sort            Sort
                               |              |
 DB      ------> Sort ------> Join --------> Join -------> Table/File
(table1)                     Buildung        Room
```

Comment: I will give this a try i just came to a solution last night i was going to update it.  but will still run this logic to see which performs better.  I ended up with a filter because they're are actually more than just two types in the table but i only care about those two.  Then used a vertical pivot and grouped by alert id and pivoted on type and number with array size of 2.  then sent through the transform to perform my if else logic.  I'll throw a diagram up when i get a chance

Comment: Well there are always more solutions to a problem but other people have to understand it as well - transparency is a good thing - and I think my solution is straight forward.